# Label does not update on button click

Tags: python, tkinter

We have to make a test for elementary school kids to test there skills in math. I need the label on the left to have a random equation, and the right have an entry form, and the far right to have a button that checks if the answer they gave is correct. If they got it right a new equation is given.

```
from tkinter import Label, Frame, Entry, Button, LEFT, RIGHT, END, TOP, END
from tkinter.messagebox import showinfo
from random import randrange

class Ed(Frame):
    'Simple arithmetic education app'
    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        'constructor'
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.pack()
        Ed.new_problem(self)
        Ed.make_widgets(self)
        self.tries = 0

    def make_widgets(self):
        'defines Ed widgets'
        if self.plusminus == 1: 
            Label(self, text=(self.a ,"+" ,self.b)).pack(side=LEFT)
        else:
            Label(self, text=(self.a, "-" ,self.b)).pack(side=LEFT)       
        self.ent = Entry(self)
        self.ent.pack(side=LEFT)        
        Button(self, text='Enter', command=self.evaluate).pack(side=RIGHT)

    def new_problem(self):
        'creates new arithmetic problem'
        self.a = randrange(1,10,1)
        self.b = randrange(1,10,1)
        self.c = randrange(1,10,1)
        if self.c < 5:
            self.total = self.a + self.b
            self.plusminus = 1     #plusminus = plus
        else:
            self.total = self.a - self.b
            self.plusminus = 0     #plusminus = minus

    def evaluate(self):
        'handles button "Enter" clicks by comparing answer in entry to correct result'
        if self.total == eval(self.ent.get()):
            showinfo(title='YAY', message='You are CORRECT!')
            self.ent.delete(0,END)
        else:
            self.ent.delete(0,END)
            self.ent.insert(END, 'Wrong. Try again.')
            self.tries+=1


Ed().mainloop()
```

The problem is the equation does not update when the answer is correct. So when I enter 12 when the question is 8 + 4. It cays correct but keeps 8 + 4 tho I want it to change to a new equation.

Comment: A giant wall of code with no real explanation of why it doesn't work is unlikely to get a good answer.

Comment: Not sure what else I can give you in terms of info. It doesnt repeat after entering the correct answer. Thats the problem

Comment: Generally, the idea is to provide a smaller sample of code that only shows the problem. Remove all of the `new_problem` cruft, reduce it down to the button & whatever minimal widgets you need for the behaviour, and have `evaluate` just act as if it was correct. This lets us focus directly on the problem code, and usually this process will help you identify the issue yourself more often than not.

Comment: It really helps if you make sure your code is indented correctly, so that people can copy&paste it to test it without having to edit it. It's also [the convention](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/) that you use triple double-quotes for docstrings. Mentioning the version you're using is also helpful, the `tkinter` module is named differently in the 2.x standard lib.

Comment: Still new here and not really sure how to indent it correctly cause I could not find a indent button. and its difficult to do it manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're only calling `new_problem` when your `Ed` object is instantiated. It's never called again afterwards, and doing so won't actually change the existing set up, as you only create the labels for your widget once, also at instantiation.

What you need to do is pass in a `tkinter.StringVar` to your `Label` widget, and then `set` the arithmetic problem on that variable. You then run `new_problem` after each successful answer.

I've updated your code slightly to use `super` and run methods directly on the instance rather than via the class, but this should work:

```
from tkinter import Label, Frame, Entry, Button, LEFT, RIGHT, END, TOP, END, StringVar
from tkinter.messagebox import showinfo
from random import randrange

class Ed(Frame):
    """Simple arithmetic education app"""
    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        """constructor"""
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.tries = 0
        self.problem = StringVar()
        self.make_widgets()
        self.new_problem()
        self.pack()

    def make_widgets(self):
        """defines Ed widgets"""
        self.label = Label(self, textvariable=self.problem)
        self.label.pack(side=LEFT)
        self.ent = Entry(self)
        self.ent.pack(side=LEFT)
        Button(self, text='Enter', command=self.evaluate).pack(side=RIGHT)

    def new_problem(self):
        """creates new arithmetic problem"""
        self.tries = 0
        self.a = randrange(1,10,1)
        self.b = randrange(1,10,1)
        if randrange(1,10,1) < 5:
            self.total = self.a + self.b
            self.plusminus = '+'
        else:
            self.total = self.a - self.b
            self.plusminus = '-'
        self.problem.set( (self.a , self.plusminus, self.b) )

    def evaluate(self):
        """handles button "Enter" clicks by comparing answer in entry to correct result"""
        if self.total == int(self.ent.get()):
            showinfo(title='YAY', message='You are CORRECT!')
            self.ent.delete(0,END)
            self.new_problem()
        else:
            self.ent.delete(0,END)
            self.ent.insert(END, 'Wrong. Try again.')
            self.tries += 1

Ed().mainloop()
```

I've also changed your `eval` to an `int`...you *really* don't want to be doing that, because it enables users to inject python code into your application.

For example, I can type the following as my "answer":

```
showinfo(title="Blah", message="Look ma - No hands!")
```

That would just bring up a simple message box, but the door is wide open for more involved mischief.

Comment: Just to be clear: you don't _need_ to use a `StringVar`. That is definitely a convenient way to solve the problem, but you can also reconfigure the widget to change the text that is displayed (eg: `self.label.configure(text="your new problem here...")`